# QuickFix.ConfigError: Configuration failed: FileLogPath not defined

Tags: c#, quickfix

when I set parameter FileLogPath in my quickfix config file (with value: outgoing) and try to do something like this:

```
                SessionSettings sessionSettings = new SessionSettings(CfgFile);
                FileStoreFactory fileStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(sessionSettings);
                FileLogFactory fileLogFactory = new FileLogFactory(sessionSettings); 
                ScreenLogFactory screenLogFactory = new ScreenLogFactory(sessionSettings);
                MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();
```

and after that tried to initialize socketInitiator with:

```
socketInitiator = new ThreadedSocketInitiator(application, fileStoreFactory, sessionSettings, fileLogFactory, messageFactory);
```

I get exception

```
QuickFix.ConfigError: Configuration failed: FileLogPath not defined
```

but when for FileLogFactory I set direct path

```
                FileLogFactory fileLogFactory = new FileLogFactory("outgoing");
```

everything is working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Config file looks something like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
[SESSION]
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
FileStorePath=incoming
FileLogPath=outgoing
SenderSubId=xxxxx
Password=yyyyy
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
SocketConnectHost=aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
SocketConnectPort=bbb
CheckLatency=N
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompId=rrrrrr
TargetCompId=vvvvvv
DataDictionary=./Specs/FIX44.xml
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

please try to move the

```
FileStorePath=incoming 
FileLogPath=outgoing
```

in the config [DEFAULT] section.

Comment: Why can't they be in the [SESSION] section?